# continous fermenting

Tags: fermentation

I am brewing milestones black pearl and have added 500g of malt extract. the wort started at an sg of 1060. It has been quite an impressive fermentation that is still continuing after 3 weeks but the sg for the last week will not drop below 1012. The instructions say to bottle once below 1009. Should I bottle now or wait it out. How long can it stay in fermenting bucket before going bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.012 is a very reasonable terminal gravity for a 1.060 OG stout.

If the gravity is stable over the course of multiple days, than it has reached its terminal/final gravity, and you can proceed to bottling.

The beer can stay in the primary fermentor for weeks, yet, without worry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Its still bubbling away so will just leave it a few more days and see if it settles.

Comment: @user12736, remember to accept jsled's answer if you are happy with it. (Click the Green Tick). Cheers